Issue with Frequent Updates to Jetpack Compose Glance Widget
I'm developing an application using Jetpack Compose and I have some widgets created using Glance Widget. I need to update a counter on the widget every time I receive a notification in the application. Notifications can arrive very frequently, up to 4 times per second, but can also have larger intervals of 10-15 seconds.
To update the widget, I'm using the
suspend fun GlanceAppWidget.updateAll(context: Context): Unit  method every time a notification is received. However, I'm encountering an issue where the widget sometimes updates the counter but sometimes it doesn't.
My questions are:

Are there any limitations on how often a widget can be updated using Glance?
What is the best approach to ensure the widget reliably updates the counter every time a notification is received, especially considering the high frequency of updates?

Any advice or best practices would be greatly appreciated!

I do not know if Glance somehow makes things worse, but IMHO you are doomed. "Are there any limitations on how often a widget can be updated" -- there are hundreds of launchers. How frequently they are capable of updating app widgets is largely up to their developers. I would not assume that you can reliably update an app widget at high frequency.

There are no limitations on how often the composable is recomposed.We can't initialise the recomposition process manually. If the parameters of the Composable function you are using is updated, It will get recomposed with the new data automatically. Please refer this documentation https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/mental-model#recomposition

I am talking specifically about the widgets
suspend fun GlanceAppWidget.updateAll(context: Context): Unit
sometimes updates all the widgets and sometimes is not getting called.
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets#MetaData
Defines how often the widget framework requests an update from the AppWidgetProvider by calling the onUpdate() callback method. The actual update isn't guaranteed to occur exactly on time with this value, and we recommend updating as infrequently as possible—no more than once an hour—to conserve the batter

Facing the same issue, below are my observations

If you look at the update code inside the library, it talks about session and lock, the logs will also say something similar.
Once the widget is updated from the app or a new widget is created, the worker session (produced by Glance lib) is locked and released after 45-50 sec.
Any updates made during that 45-50-second interval are ignored, so for a successful update, the app needs to wait for that time window to pass. You can confirm this time window by watching the logs (provided one below)
I don't know much about session and locks but all this is true as per my testing.
My approach: I am keeping a flag for widgetUpdate = true/false and invoking the updateWidget() code only in onStop() to prevent frequent updates, as the user cannot see the widget without going to the home screen. Our app is still in development; I have no idea what to do about it.

This is the log you should look for:
Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=69cc3029-d1b1-4e9a-9084-108baa942a49, tags={ androidx.glance.session.SessionWorker } ]

Please update if anyone got any fix/work around.
